# How to import foreign key data to another table (sql server)?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, foreign-keys, primary-key

First, here's my database schema...

[image]

I would like a stored procedure where I can select all from tblEvent + Name from tblConferences (based on ConID) + Name from tblCandidates (based on CanID).

Thanks in advance!

To be honest, I tried searching for the solution, but all in vain.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Your title does not match your question?  The title states: "import foreign key data to another table" but your question instead asks about how to create a stored procedure that selects information.  Then you should be including your attempt at creating a stored procedure that selects information and edit the title so it reflects what you're asking.

Comment: Most databases uses JOINs to select data from multiple tables. You can join your tables together by the keys (you can see by the arrows how stuff is connected), and select the data you need. something like: select * from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t2.id = t.id inner join table3 t3 ON t3.anotherid = t2.anotherId

Comment: Yep you do that kind of thing using [joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver16). They are fundamental in a relational database.